# Why replacing an uncertainty set with its convex hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given $U$ an uncertainty set, I don't see the point in saying that

*"For most models of robust optimization, it is easy to prove that changing from $U$ to its convex hull does not change the problem, as the worst case in the inner maximization problem will be attained in an extreme point anyway."* ([page 3, 2.2](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2017/09/6199.pdf) ).

Or similarly,

*"The uncertainty set $U$ can be replaced by its convex hull $\operatorname{conv}(U)$, i.e., the smallest convex set that includes $U$, because testing the feasibility of a solution with respect to $U$ is equivalent to taking the supremum of the left hand side of a constraint over $U$, which yields the same
optimal objective value if the maximization is $\operatorname{conv}(U)$."* ([page 3, E.3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02634))

If the problem described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912485/convexity-or-not?noredirect=1#comment8069072_3912485) is already convex, what is the sense to replacing $U$ with its hull?

Comment: From a cursory glance, it looks like these papers are proving results under the assumption that their uncertainty set $U$ is convex when, in general, it needn't be. These paragraphs are saying that the non-convex $U$ case is no more tricky. What they are doing is considering the problem for possibly *non-convex* $U$, and reducing the problem down to the convex case, by considering the problem with $\operatorname{conv} U$ substituted for $U$. So, there should be no problem assuming $U$ is convex, and if you have a non-convex $U$, then replace $U$ with $\operatorname{conv} U$, and it works out.

Comment: @user847970 First at all, thanks for your answer. Ok, only one thing I really don't understand: if the problem $\underset{x}{\operatorname{min}}\begin{Bmatrix}
\operatorname{c}^T\operatorname{x} : A(\zeta)\operatorname{x} \leq \operatorname{b},\forall \zeta \in U
\end{Bmatrix}$ is always convex because "*an intersection of infinitely many halfspaces is still convex*" (please, see the third link on my post: Michal Adamaszek), I *already* know that $U$ is convex. So there would be no reason to replace $U$ with $\operatorname{conv}(U)$. Or not?

Comment: That's right. If you already know $U$ is convex, there's no need to do replace $U$ with $\operatorname{conv} U$ (as they are already the same thing. But, if you ever need to do this same problem with a $U$ that isn't convex, then you know what to do!